# Is this the best way of doing a informational banner?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I am currently displaying a SKNode with child SKLabelNodes to display some informational text , which then fade out after 20 seconds.

I would like to be able to have them above a rectangle behind the SKLabelNodes, which temporarily blocks out the nodes below, but it doesn't seem to work when I use a SKShapeNode which is a rectangle underneath the SKLabelNodes as an intermediate parent between the original SKNode , nor if I substitute the SKShapeNode for the original SKNode; I can see the SKLabelNodes being flickered onto the screen, but then immediately they can't be seen. How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: can you show relevant parts of your code?

Comment: The Label nodes were using absolute coordinates, and the rect wasn't

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: You can change the order nodes are drawn by setting their zPosition property. This is relative to the parent zPosition and positive values will cause the node to be drawn later (on top of other nodes)

Comment: Yes i made zPosition 1.0 for the labels, and 0.9 for the rectangle, and made sure the rectangle was  midx-hw  midy-hh right behind the Label nodes so they weren't being clipped out by the parent rectangle being nowhere near them in the x y plane.